# Inserir escala no eixo y para geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quero plotar as colunas `analise1`, `analise2`, `analise3` em um único gráfico de linhas mas com escalas diferentes, pois a amplitude da coluna `analise1` é muito maior que das outras duas colunas. No eixo x estariam os anos que estão na coluna `Período`, não coloquei em formato date pois o último dado dessa coluna é referente a vários anos. Essa visualização permitiria ver o comportamento das três análises ao longo do tempo.

Pensei em usar ggplot e facet_wrap, mas me esbarrei na seguinte dificuldade: como definir o intervalo em y, visto que os limites seriam justamente o menor e maior valor de cada coluna? Precisaria inserir uma coluna em `df` para cada um dos gráficos e jogar valores aleatórios dentro do intervalo da amplitude de cada coluna?

Meus dados:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Período = c("1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", 
"1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", 
"2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", 
"2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", 
"2019", "30anos"), analise1 = c(-17.4, 0.6, -2.3, -14.3, 1.8, 
-22.1, -28, 1.4, -26.1, -18.6, -20.4, -35.1, -25.8, -26.8, -17.1, 
-32.4, -17.5, -13.4, -32.7, -18.2, -22.6, -23.4, -43.5, -17.1, 
-35.2, -22.5, -15.8, -25.5, -19.6, -36.4, -20.9), analise2 = c(0.08, 
0.05, 0.03, 0.14, 0.26, 0.09, 0.11, 0.22, 0.16, -0.05, 0.17, 
0.13, 0, 0.16, 0.09, 0.16, 0.1, 0.28, 0.17, 0.05, 0.22, 0.21, 
0.19, 0.18, 0.16, 0.22, 0.28, 0.18, 0.29, 0.08, 0.15), analise3 = c(0.33, 
0.36, 0.35, 0.44, 0.61, 0.34, 0.36, 0.5, 0.42, 0.29, 0.44, 0.39, 
0.32, 0.42, 0.4, 0.42, 0.38, 0.54, 0.44, 0.38, 0.47, 0.48, 0.48, 
0.44, 0.42, 0.49, 0.53, 0.44, 0.55, 0.34, 0.42)), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ideia de criar painéis com `facet_wrap` é muito boa. Para isso, a primeira providência é colocar o `df` em formato longo:

```r
head(df)
#>   Período analise1 analise2 analise3
#> 1    1990    -17.4     0.08     0.33
#> 2    1991      0.6     0.05     0.36
#> 3    1992     -2.3     0.03     0.35
#> 4    1993    -14.3     0.14     0.44
#> 5    1994      1.8     0.26     0.61
#> 6    1995    -22.1     0.09     0.34

library(tidyverse)

df_longo <-
  df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(analise1, analise2, analise3))

head(df_longo)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   Período name      value
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 1990    analise1 -17.4 
#> 2 1990    analise2   0.08
#> 3 1990    analise3   0.33
#> 4 1991    analise1   0.6 
#> 5 1991    analise2   0.05
#> 6 1991    analise3   0.36
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Foi possível empilhar as colunas `analise1`, `analise2` e `analise3` com o uso da função `pivot_longer`. Agora vamos utilizar a nova coluna `name` para definir os painéis e as cores das análises.

```r
ggplot(df_longo, aes(x = Período, y = value, colour = name, group = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(seq(1990, 2019, by = 5), "30anos"),
                   labels = c(seq(1990, 2019, by = 5), "30 anos")) +
  labs(x = "Período", y = "Valor", colour = "Análise") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Perceba o uso do argumento `scales = "free_y"` dentro da função `facet_wrap`. Com ele foi possível dizer para o `ggplot` calcular automaticamente a melhor amplitude para o eixo Y de cada painel criado.

Os comandos a partir do uso da função `scale_x_discrete` tem apenas funcionalidades estéticas. Achei que intervalos anuais não geravam uma boa visualização para os dados, então coloquei intervalos de 5 anos, mais o resultado agregado para 30 anos. Isso pode ser facilmente alterado.

Comment: Marcus Nunes muito obrigada! Como sempre, fantástica sua orientação e didática. Tenho uma dúvida no código que você fez: é possível com o `facet_wrap` colocar cada gráfico "um em cima do outro" ao invés de "um ao lado do outro"?

Comment: Coloque a opção `ncol = 1` dentro do `facet_wrap`

Comment: Poderia me informar como aumentar o tamanho das facetas (analise1, analise2, analise3) e da legenda? Consegui alterar somente os tamanhos e estilos dos títulos e escalas.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma que encontrei de colocar o eixo secundário foi utilizando o plotly. Foi o que entendi que você está procurando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Realmente há uma discrepância muito grande da variável análise 1 em relação as outras duas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Douglas obrigada pela sugestão! Da forma que você fez também gera o eixo secundário, mas eu gostaria de uma forma que o eixo ficasse independente, pois considero que quando analiso mais de 2 variáveis, principalmente se os valores forem muito diferentes (máximos e mínimos), colocá-las da forma como você sugeriu, pode gerar dificuldade na análise ou até mesmo confusão. Mas super válida a abordagem que você fez, pois em caso de 2 variáveis, pode ser uma opção sim! Obrigada novamente.